# Sum of fitted models with sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying to do something that involves taking the sum of two fitted models such that the output is another LinearRegression type object. I have fitted the two models using the standard LinearRegression method from sklearn.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

reg_1 = LinearRegression().fit(X1, y)
reg_2 = LinearRegression().fit(X2, y)
```

and I want to be able to produce something like

```
reg = reg_1 + reg_2
```

such that I can still do standard operations such as

```
reg.predict(X3)
```

Is there an easy way to do this, clearly I can obtain the coefficients of both `reg_1` and `reg_2` so if I can define `reg` ussing those, it would work but I couldn't see a way to do this.

Comment: Curious as to what is your motivation for wanting to do this?

Comment: Also do X1 and X2 contain different sets of features, or are they just different datasets with the same features?

Comment: @TobyPetty it is too difficult to explain why I want to do it, but long story short they are just different datasets with the same features.

Comment: Ok see my answer for one way of doing this. I would definitely recommend just trying to combine the datasets and creating one model though.

Comment: I kind of agree with Toby. Having said that, if you're serious about trying to do something like `reg = reg_1 + reg_2`, you might just look into creating a custom estimator that integrates the two. [Sklearn Custom Estimator](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html#developing-scikit-learn-estimators) might be useful

Comment: Have a look at `mlens` package.

Comment: And sklearn [VotingRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingRegressor.html?highlight=votingregressor#sklearn.ensemble.VotingRegressor) might be useful if you want to weight predictions of the models.

Answer (score 1):

Since your reason for doing this is that "they are just different datasets with the same features" I would recommend simply appending the datasets and creating one model on all data.

But if this isn't possible for some reason you could do this by manually setting the `coef_` and `intercept_` attributes of a third linear model as the averages of the first two, such as:

```
reg = LinearRegression()
reg.coef_ = np.array([np.mean(t) for t in zip(reg_1.coef_, reg_2.coef_)])
reg.intercept_ = np.mean([reg_1.intercept_, reg_2.intercept_])
```

Then you can just use the `reg.predict(X3)` method as usual to make predictions from the combined averages of the 2 linear models' terms.

There are dangers in this approach though, if for example one of the datasets used to fit the original models is much larger than the other one, then the smaller dataset's intercept and coefficient terms would be over-weighted in the combined model, and you would probably want to do some weighting when averaging the intercept and coefficient terms.